# My images jumps when I scroll on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I hope someone can help.

I am playing around on a charity site I was asked to make, but the image keeps jumping when I scroll on the page.

[As you can see here](http://www.empoweringlovefoundation.com/gallery.html)

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Ignore the rest of the site, as I am still working out how solve the other issues.

I am very new to coding

HTML (I only added a few photos, there are so many):

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<table class="topnav" id="navigation" cellspacing="2">
   <tr>
     <td><a href="news.html"> Newsletters </a></td>
     <td><a href="events.html"> Fundraisers </a></td>
     <td><a href="index.html"> About us </a></td>
     <td><a href="widows.html"> The widows </a></td>
     <td><a href="helping.html"> What we do </a></td>
     <td><a href="donate.html"> Donate </a></td>
     <td><a href="contact.html"> Contact us </a></td>
     <td><a href="gallery.html"> Gallery </a></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<!-- GALLERY -->

<div id="myBtnContainer" class="btndiv">
   <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('widows')"> Photos of Widows</button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('videos')"> Videos of Widows </button>
   <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('events')"> Charity events</button>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">

   <div class="column widows" class="onecol">
     <div class="content">
       <img src="gallery/images/widows/16.png" alt="widows">
     </div>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

   <div class="column widows">
     <div class="content">
       <img src="gallery/images/widows/20.png" alt="widows" style="width:100%">
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column widows">
      <div class="content">
         <img src="gallery/images/widows/3.png" alt="widows" style="width:100%">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column widows">
       <div class="content">
          <img src="gallery/images/widows/4.png" alt="widows" style="width: 100%;">
       </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* NAVIGATION BAR */

 .topnav {
   background-color: #ff9f80;
   overflow: auto;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: Perpetua, sans-serif;
   font-size: 120%;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
 }

 /* NAVIGATION LINKS */

 .topnav a {
   color: #8b0000;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   padding: 5% 4%;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 /* STICKY NAVIGATION BAR */

 .sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }

 .sticky + .content {
   padding-top: 102px;
 }

 /* CHANGE COLOR WHEN HOVERING OVER NAVIGATION BAR */

 .topnav a:hover {
   background-color: #ffc6b3;
   color: #8b0000;
 }

 /* FONT FOR NAVIGATION LINKS */

nav {
   font-family: Perpetua, sans-serif;
}

/* GALLERY */

.btndiv {
   text-align: center;
 }

* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 /* CENTER WEBSITE */
 .main {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
  }


 .row {
    margin: 8px -16px;
  }

  /* PADDING BETWEEN COLUMNS */
  .row,
  .row > .column {
    padding: 8px;
  }

  /* THREE EQUAL COLUMS NEXT TO EACH OTHER */
  .column {
     float: left;
     width: 33.33%;
     display: none; /* Hide columns by default */
   }

   /* CLEAR FLOATS AFTER ROWS */ 
   .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

  /* CONTENT */
 .content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
  }

 /* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
 .show {
    display: block;
 }

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   background-color: #ff9f80;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 15px 50px;
   font-size: 100%;
   color: #8b0000;
 }

 /* Add a grey background color on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
   background-color: #ffc6b3;
}

/* Add a dark background color to the active button */
.btn.active {
   background-color: #b32d00;
   color: white;
 }

 /* IMAGE RESIZING */

 .onecol {
   position: fixed;
   width: 150%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block;
   column-span: all;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
filterSelection("all") // Execute the function and show all columns
function filterSelection(c) {
   var x, i;
   x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
   if (c == "all") c = "";
// Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements,     and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
   if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
   var i, arr1, arr2;
   arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
   arr2 = name.split(" ");
   for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
        element.className += " " + arr2[i];
      }
    }
  }

  // Hide elements that are not selected
  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1); 
      }
     }
     element.className = arr1.join(" ");
    }

   // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
   var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
   var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
   for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
       current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active", "");
       this.className += "active";
      });
    }
```

Comment: please include the html and css for the NAV and positioning of the html elements in css for body, header, image, heading, also include any javascript used for positioning the nav on scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back, I have editted the code into the post

Answer (score 0):

It could be more helpful to understand if you could explain your problem more thoroughly.
To my understanding, if you want images to be sticky while scrolling you can use the CSS property of sticky

```
img.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Another problem that I encounter is, when you scroll down, a class of sticky gets included in your table tag.
Check your code where this is happening.

Comment: Hi Thank you for getting back, I will have a look and also try your sticky code.